# Python module not being seen by bash script on reboot

Tags: python, bash, cron, raspberry-pi

I have a python program I am trying to get to run on reboot on my Raspberry Pi. Whenever I just run the bash script in my terminal, it works fine. Whenever I add the @reboot line to crontab, it throws an error saying that one of the modules in the python script isn't installed. Below are the scripts/errors.

Bash script:
cd
cd /home/raspberrypi/Desktop/Spring2023
python test_exception.py
cd

Crontab addition:
@reboot bash /home/raspberrypi/Desktop/Spring2023/Launcher2.bash >/home/pi/logs/cronlogs 2>&1

Whenever I do bash `/home/raspberrypi/Desktop/Spring2023/Launcher2.bash` in my terminal, the script executes fine and the python code runs. On reboot however, it throws this error in the logs:

`import adafruit_tca9548a ModuleNotFoundError: No module named adafruit_tca9548a`

Tried bash script, works in terminal but not on reboot. Tried different ways of executing in both crontab and terminal, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Could this be caused by running your script as root? Python's pip installs packages to a user directory by default when not able to write them to the system directory, and if Python were running as root, it wouldn't look in the user directory for packages. Can you add information about what user the script is running as in both scenarios?

Comment: @NickODell I added sudo -u to run as user and it worked! Thanks